Find the Laurent series of $z^2e^{1/z}$ in the neighborhood of $z=0$
Find the Laurent series of $z^2e^{1/z}$ in the neighborhood of $z=0$.

Just looking for solution verification. I have:
\begin{align}
    \begin{split}
        z^2 e^{1/z} &= z^2 \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\left( \frac{1}{z}\right)^n}{n!} = z^2 \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!z^n} =  \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n! z^{n-2}} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^{-n+2}}{n!} \\ 
    \end{split}
\end{align}
Does this look good?

Good. I guess it is correct.

@GregMartin Thanks. I was mixing up two different ideas. It has now been removed.
